# MySQL Insert - How to prevent two foreign IDs in the same table from being identical?

Tags: mysql, database

Trying to make a forum database where a user can follow other user(s) and vice versa. For this I have two tables "user" and "follow_user".

This works just fine:

INSERT INTO `forum`.`follow_user` ( `follower_id`, `being_followed_id` ) VALUES ( 13, 14);
INSERT INTO `forum`.`follow_user` ( `follower_id`, `being_followed_id` ) VALUES ( 13, 15);
INSERT INTO `forum`.`follow_user` ( `follower_id`, `being_followed_id` ) VALUES ( 14, 13);
INSERT INTO `forum`.`follow_user` ( `follower_id`, `being_followed_id` ) VALUES ( 14, 15);
INSERT INTO `forum`.`follow_user` ( `follower_id`, `being_followed_id` ) VALUES ( 15, 13);
INSERT INTO `forum`.`follow_user` ( `follower_id`, `being_followed_id` ) VALUES ( 15, 14);

**The problem:** A user shouldn't be able to follow himself (currently my DB allows it):

INSERT INTO `forum`.`follow_user` ( `follower_id`, `being_followed_id` ) VALUES ( 13, 13);

```
CREATE TABLE `forum`.`user` (
`user_id` SMALLINT(5) NOT NULL,
`user_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`user_email` VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL,
`user_signature` VARCHAR(240) NULL,
`user_created` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`user_updated` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`));


CREATE TABLE `follow_user` (
`follower_id` smallint(5) NOT NULL,
`being_followed_id` smallint(5) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`follower_id`,`being_followed_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `unique_index` (`follower_id`,`being_followed_id`),
KEY `follower_id_fk_idx` (`follower_id`),
KEY `being_followed_id_fk_idx` (`being_followed_id`),
CONSTRAINT `being_followed_id_fk` 
FOREIGN KEY (`being_followed_id`)
REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`) 
ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `follower_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`follower_id`) REFERENCES `user`(`user_id`) 
ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='   ';
```

Comment: probably this is something you should enforce at the application level.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trigger to execute before insert, to make sure the two columns don't have the same value.

```
CREATE TABLE `follow_user` (
    `follower_id` smallint(5) NOT NULL,
    `being_followed_id` smallint(5) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`follower_id`,`being_followed_id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `unique_index` (`follower_id`,`being_followed_id`),
    KEY `follower_id_fk_idx` (`follower_id`),
    KEY `being_followed_id_fk_idx` (`being_followed_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `being_followed_id_fk` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`being_followed_id`)
    REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`) 
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT `follower_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`follower_id`) REFERENCES `user`(`user_id`) 
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='   ';

CREATE TRIGGER follow_user_before_insert 
BEFORE INSERT ON follow_user FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.follower_id = NEW.being_followed_id
    THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Cannot add or update row: follower_id must be different from being_followed_id'
    END IF
END
/
```

However, as @ADyson mentionned in the comments, it may be simpler to do at the application level, with a simple `if else` statement.

```
if(followerId != beingFollowedId) {
    // insert
}
else {
    // throw exception or return error code/message
}
```

Comment: @WillemRenzema well, TIL, modified the answer

Comment: I tried your suggested solution with the trigger and I cannot make the trigger part syntax to be accepted by the DB.

It says "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 1
Line 28, column 1"

Anyhow I tried to change ENDIF to END IF , and I tried to add delimiter before and after the trigger , no effect. Anyhow I think I will go along the path of accepting and surrender to the method of not allowing it per user interface level.

Comment: @JanHannibalsen you're right, that was a mistake on my part, I edited the answer. You can also check the [MySQL Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html) for if structures